# How to create an Oracle stored procedure with a parameter?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, parameters

I'm a novice at SQL and am trying to create a Stored Procedure in Oracle database. The SPROC needs two date parameters (from_date and to_date) for my report to run. Maybe I'm confusing this with SQL Server code.

My code looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uSP_RevPerSalesman

   @from_date DATE
   @to_date DATE

AS

BEGIN

SELECT DISTINCT
   C.CUSTOMER_CODE
 , MS.SALESMAN_NAME
 , SUM(C.REVENUE_AMT)

FROM
   C_REVENUE_ANALYSIS C
 , M_CUSTOMER MC
 , M_SALESMAN MS

WHERE
   C.CUSTOMER_CODE = MC.CUSTOMER_CODE AND
   MC.SALESMAN_CODE = MS.SALESMAN_CODE AND
   MC.COMP_CODE = 'W1' AND
   MS.COMP_CODE = '00' AND
   C.REVENUE_DATE >= :from_date AND 
   C.REVENUE_DATE <= :to_date

GROUP BY
   C.CUSTOMER_CODE, MS.SALESMAN_NAME

ORDER BY
   C.CUSTOMER_CODE

END

GO
```

I get an error message when I run this code. The error message I get is:

> ERROR ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

When I run only the SELECT code, it works and gives me the right results. I just can't seem to make this into a SPROC.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `GO`, that is not valid in Oracle. Try a semicolon at the end instead, or a /, depending on where you're running this.

Comment: Thank you for replying Barett. I removed the 'GO' at the end but that was a NoGo. Still 'invalid SQL statement'.  --  I am using MS Visual Studio 2012 Shell to run this.